# How to save a boolean value in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, boolean, laravel-6.2

I have

Migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->boolean('wifi');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->text('desc');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**BookingController.php**'s `store` method:

```
public function store()
    {
        $booking = new Booking();
        $booking->user_id = 1;
        $booking->name = request('name');
        $booking->phone = request('phone');
        $booking->wifi = request('wifi');
        $booking->address = request('address');
        $booking->desc = request('desc');
        $booking->save();

        return redirect('/bookings');
    }
```

**create.blad.php**'s the part of `wifi` checkbox:

```
<div class="field">
   <label for="wifi" class="label">Wi-Fi</label>
   <div class="control">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check" name="wifi" id="address">
   <div>
</div>
```

When I trying creating a record, I'm getting error:

1) I'm trying to save a value as FALSE:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'wifi' cannot be null (SQL: insert
>   into `bookings` (`user_id`, `name`, `phone`, `wifi`, `address`,
>   `desc`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Dragon, 12341234, ?,
>   asdfasdfasdkf hsadfasdf, asdfasdfas, 2020-02-27 07:10:55, 2020-02-27
>   07:10:55))

2) And when I checked Wi-Fi checkbox (TRUE value)

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
>   format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column
>   `kaganat`.`bookings`.`wifi` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `bookings`
>   (`user_id`, `name`, `phone`, `wifi`, `address`, `desc`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (1, Dragon, 12341234, on, asdfasdfasdkf
>   hsadfasdf, asdfasdfasdfsafaa, 2020-02-27 07:17:15, 2020-02-27
>   07:17:15))

**UPDATE:**

SOLUTION:

Update from

```
$booking->wifi = request('wifi');
```

to

```
$booking->wifi = request()->has('wifi');
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input You are getting the name value out of the checkbox and not if the checkbox is selected or not

Comment: Can you please submit an answer by showing how it should be? I will try it and accept. Unfortunately, the documentation didn't give any idea how to fix and where...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with the has method, if the value has been submitted and therefore you can insert true or false.

You can read it up here in the documenation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input

So it has to be something like `$request->has('wifi')`. The has method will return true, if the value is present in the request. If this value is true, you can assign true to the field, otherwise false. This would be my approach.

If you need an example, you can look at this question [Passing a boolean value from checkbox in Laravel 5.8 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997601/passing-a-boolean-value-from-checkbox-in-laravel-5-8-form)

Comment: Thanks, it took me some time to figure out. I was able to fix the issue by refactoring like `$booking->wifi = request()->has('wifi');`