# Laravel proble with checkbox and boolean values to database

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i'm trying to post match information about each player.
**match_facts**  schema:

```
Schema::create('match_facts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->uuid('match_id');
        $table->uuid('player_id');
        $table->integer('minutes')->nullable();
        $table->integer('goals')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('yellowCard');
        $table->boolean('redCard');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

main goal is to post all players to database which have checkbox "in squad"
Now doesn't matter if checkbox is cheked or not, record for each player is created.
Also problem with booleans. The request does not retrieve them.

Here is my html code:

```
    @foreach($match->homeTeam->players as $player)
     <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{$player->id}}</th>
            <td class = "col-md-6" name = "player[]" value = "{{$player->id}}">{{$player->name}} {{$player->surname}}</td>
            <td align="center" class= "col-md-2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="squad[]" value=""></td>
            <td class = "col-md-2"><input name="minutes[]"  class="form-control"></td>
            <td class = "col-md-2"><input name="goals[]" class="form-control"></td>
            <td align="center" class= "col-md-2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="yellowCard[]" value=""></td>
            <td align="center" class= "col-md-2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="redCard[]" value=""></td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and controller:

```
if (isset($request->squad)) {
                 foreach ( $match_players as $k => $p  ) {
                    $data[] = [
                        'match_id' => $match->id,
                        'player_id' => $p->id,
                        'minutes' => $request['minutes'][$k],
                        'goals' => $request['goals'][$k],
                        'yellowCard' => $request['yellowCard'][$k],
                        'redCard' => $request['redCard'][$k],
                    ];
                }
            }                 
                if(count($match_players)>0){
                  Match_fact::insert( $data );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a boolean value from checkbox in Laravel 5.8 form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997601/passing-a-boolean-value-from-checkbox-in-laravel-5-8-form)

Comment: You're explicitly setting `value=""` on the input, so of course it won't have a value!

Comment: @miken32, getting this error: ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Look at the dupe. Use $request->filled()

Comment: @miken32, I tried but failed